# Mongoose findOne not returning anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a READ route in my API that doesn't seem to return anything when given an ID, I'm not 100% sure what is going on, since my READ route for getting everything in my mongoDB is working.

```
app.get('api/notes/:id', (req,res) => {
            let id = req.params.id
            Note.findOne(id, (err, note) => {
                err ? res.send(err) : res.json(note);
            })
        })
```

The one that works looks like this:

```
app.get('/api/notes', (req, res) => {
            Note.find((err, notes) => {
                err ? res.send(err) : res.json(notes);
            });
        });
```

I've used this route a million times, but it just doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed slash(/) before this 'api/notes/:id' ,you can also use the code ,findOne to find the value.

```
 router.get('/api/notes/:id', function (req, res) {
     let id = req.params.id
    Note.findOne({id: id}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({status: 0, message: err});
                }
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({status: 0, msg: "not found"});
                }
                res.json({status: 1, id: user._id, message: " success"});
            })
    });
```

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that. Thanks!